# I added my project to my Git Repository but it is not in TFS source control

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I cannot build my .Net application and I find that it is searching for a project that is part of the application but not in source control.
I can't seem to find a way of adding it.
I put it in my Git Repository but it does not show up as being under source control. How do I fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Right-click it, do you have the option to add it to source control?

Comment: I tried that. No.

Answer (score 0):

You could double check below things to narrow down the problem:

- Make sure you have pushed your local git repo to remote git repo on
  TFS for synchronization.
- Check if you have added the project to a new created repo, when you
  create a project, there is an option **Create new Git Repository**.
  You may checked this option.

  [image]

If so, the simplest way is manually copy the project to your original local repo, then commit and push it.